# Div is not centered correctly with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with this DIV not getting centered.
I am sure it is something with CSS,

I need some corrections to CSS below and to get rid of unnecessary CSS statements if not needed

I would like the div to be centered and 75% wide

Thanks,

```
  .css_main_popup {
    transition: opacity 10ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    align-self: center;
  }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SMT Explorer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="explorer.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main_div" style="position: relative; "></div>

        <div id="popup_factory" class="css_main_popup">
            <a class="css_close_popup" href="#" style='text-align:right' onclick="CloseFPopup()">&times;</a>
        </div>

        <div id="popup_stations" class="css_main_popup">
            <a class="css_close_popup" href="#" style='text-align:right' onclick="CloseSPopup()">&times;</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="explorer.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Can't really debug if we don't have the problem posted in codepen, jsfiddle.. anyway your problem is maybe because you are using % for height with position absolute so you are specifying the height % depending on which parent? try to use px or vh for height

Answer (score 0):

If it's a popup, it should propbably have `position: fixed`, not `absolute`. And then, these settings should work:

```
.css_main_popup {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: opacity 10ms;
}
```

So the important settings for centering (horizontally AND vertically) are `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` (no `margin`, no `align-self`)

That would result in something like this (visibility excepted):

```css
.css_main_popup {
  transition: opacity 10ms;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_main_popup"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using left and position: absolute you are able to push the div to the center of the screen.

```
.css_main_popup {
    transition: opacity 10ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;
    left: 15%;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```